# How to make a simple bytes to string converter using python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple converter but get either the errors
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?

or

TypeError: decoding str is not supported

First I tried an example, using the character ã

Which when doing

```
    encodedcharacter = input("Encode a str: ")
    print(encodedcharacter.encode('utf-8'))
```

returns

b'\xc3\xa3'

But then inputting that in and instead decoding it

```
encodedcharacter = input("Encode a str: ") # I entered "b'\xc3\xa3'"
print(encodedcharacter.decode('utf-8'))
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/decode_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    encodedcharacter = input("Encode a str: ")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?
```

I also tried

```
encodedcharacter = input("Encode a str: ") # I entered "b'\xc3\xa3'"
decoded_text = encodedcharacter.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
print(decoded_text)
```

which returns

```
b'Ã£'
```

Which is close...but not close enough

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast

encoded_string = input("Enter a byte string: ")  # Enter something like 
"b'\xc3\xa3'"

bytes_object = ast.literal_eval(encoded_string.encode('utf- 
8').decode('unicode_escape'))

# Decode the bytes object to a string
decoded_string = bytes_object.decode('utf-8')

print(decoded_string)
```

This way, you can safely convert the byte string back to a string. However, always be cautious when using **eval()** or **ast.literal_eval()**, especially with user input, to avoid security risks associated with executing arbitrary code.

Comment: import ast

encoded_bytes = input("Enter a byte string: ")  # Enter something like "b'\xc3\xa3'"
# Safely evaluate the string as Python code
bytes_object = ast.literal_eval(encoded_bytes.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape'))
# Decode the bytes object to a string
decoded_string = bytes_object.decode('utf-8')

print(decoded_string). 

oops, update this codes

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without using `ast.literal_eval`. First, get the hex parts from the input with a regular expression ('c3', 'a3'). Then convert these to integers (195, 163). You can then convert these to a byte array using the built-in `bytearray`. Finally, decode the byte array.

```
import re

# ====================
def byte_array_from_string_input(string_input):

    hex_values = re.findall(r"\\x([^\\'\"]+)", string_input)
    int_values = [int(hex, 16) for hex in hex_values]
    as_bytes = bytearray(int_values)
    return as_bytes


encoded_string = input("Enter a byte string: ")
decoded = byte_array_from_string_input(encoded_string).decode('utf-8')
print(f'Here is your decoded string:', decoded)
```

Running this in the interpreter:

```
Enter a byte string: \xc3\xa3
Here is your decoded string: ã
```

The `byte_array_from_string_input` function works whether or not the user includes b'' around the input.

Comment: Gee, thanks so much! Appreciate you.